# Bulk create records for one Model in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, bulkinsert

i have view:

```
<%= form_tag mined_materials_url do %>
  <%= render 'import_fields' %><br />
  <%= render 'import_fields' %>
  <%= button_tag :submit %>  
<% end %>
```

_import_fields.html.erb:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'mined_material[][character_id]','' %>
<%= text_field_tag 'mined_material[][material_id]','' %>
<%= text_field_tag 'mined_material[][quantity]','' %>
<%= text_field_tag 'mined_material[][price]','' %>
```

(i will add more fields via JS)

and need to insert multiple records into same model at once, but it fail to save because of error: undefined method `permit' for Array:0x00000001f63230

Params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"fFR3nWwz2Q0ivED6XXyj4ICRBtj5Rdois4N++cNnCko=",
"mined_material"=>[{"character_id"=>"1",
"material_id"=>"1",
"quantity"=>"1",
"price"=>"1"},
{"character_id"=>"2",
"material_id"=>"2",
"quantity"=>"2",
"price"=>"2"}],
"button"=>""}
```

how could i permit bulk create?

**EDIT:**
MinedMaterialsController

```
class MinedMaterialsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_mined_material, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_action :load_mined_material, only: :create
 load_and_authorize_resource


# GET /mined_materials/new
def new
  @mined_material = MinedMaterial.new
end

# POST /mined_materials
def create
  @mined_material = MinedMaterial.new(mined_material_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @mined_material.save
      format.html { redirect_to new_mined_material_path, notice: 'Mined material was successfully created.' }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
    end
  end
end

def import
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_mined_material
  @mined_material = MinedMaterial.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def mined_material_params
  params.require(:mined_material).permit(:character_id, :material_id, :quantity, :price, :paid_out, :date, :corp_tax)
end

def load_mined_material
  @mined_material = MinedMaterial.new(mined_material_params)
end

end
```

Comment: Can you show your controller code?

Comment: i am using import action

Answer (score 0):

You can change your mined_material_params method to this:

```
    params.permit({mined_material: [:character_id, :material_id, :quantity, :price, :paid_out, :date, :corp_tax]} ).require(:mined_material)
```

permit method only work if the value is a hash.

Comment: it is still saying that i cannot permit array, should i change my form somehow? or maybe i will do some model method which will do actual save to database instead of using standard create method...

Comment: can you puts the params in the mined_material_params method?  
This code  is works in my rails console:

Comment: `params = ActionController::Parameters.new({"authenticity_token"=>"fFR3nWwz2Q0ivED6XXyj4ICRBtj5Rdois4N++cNnCko=","mined_material"=>[{"character_id"=>"1","material_id"=>"1","quantity"=>"1","price"=>"1"},{"character_id"=>"2","material_id"=>"2","quantity"=>"2","price"=>"2"}],"button"=>""})`


`params.permit({mined_material: [:character_id, :material_id, :quantity, :price, :paid_out, :date, :corp_tax]} ).require(:mined_material) `


`#=> [{"character_id"=>"1", "material_id"=>"1", "quantity"=>"1", "price"=>"1"}, {"character_id"=>"2", "material_id"=>"2", "quantity"=>"2", "price"=>"2"}]`